# Hello world с пустой функцией main

Tags: c++, соревнование

Столкнулся с такой задачей на собеседовании:

> Написать программу, которая печатает в консоли фразу `Hello world`

И всё бы ничего, если бы после этого стояла точка. Но фраза продолжается:

> при условии, что функция `main()` данной программы выглядит следующим образом:

```
int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Ответ очень прост. Их даже несколько. Самый простой, основанный на свойстве глобальных статических объектов.

```
int printHelloWorld() { printf("Hello World"); return 0; }
static int testVar = printHelloWorld();
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Это, если С стиль. С++ стиль: создаем класс, в конструкторе добавляем вывод, будет вывод до main, в деструкторе - после.

Comment: можно ещё короче 
int i = puts("Hello World");
int main(void) { return 0; }

Comment: <i>создаем класс</i>
<p>
Имеется в виду - нужен объект класса :-) Т.к. само объявление класса ничего не вызывает.

Comment: А оптимизация не порежет ли инициализацию к неиспользуемой статичекой переменной? Или это только в шарпе статик инициализируется при первом обращении в коде, до этого он мертв?

Comment: @Чад хоть и поздно, но отвечу. В шарпе статик инициализируется не при первом обращении - а **при загрузке класса**. В Си/С++ может быть выкинут лишний модуль, на который нет ссылок - но если модуль присутствует, то все статические переменные будут инициализированы.

Comment: Во-первых, не понятно, почему это названо "С стилем". В языке С динамическая инициализация невозможна. Так что сам подход в самой своей сути - именно С++ стиль, что с классами, что без. Во-вторых, без предварительного обявления функции `printf` программа некорректна. Это относится и к варианту с `puts`.

Comment: Увидев этот код, удивился насколько некоторый работодатель пытается заморочиться с тестированием на собеседовании, просто нет слов!

Answer (score 204):

Используем препроцессор.

```
#define return puts("Hello World"); return

int main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Не такой красивый вариант как со статикой, но тоже работает.

Comment: Вот у меня были подобные мысли, но смутило то, что return занятое слово, разве его дефайном можно?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что дефайном можно все что угодно. В этом его мощь и... опасность :)

Comment: Старая шутка на ум пришла #define true false

Comment: И сразу второй строчкой<pre>#define false true</pre> :-)

Comment: Единственный вариант, работающий в C и C++

Comment: нет не единственный. наоборот, про решение с классом и конструктором можно сказать "единственный вариант НЕ работающий в С и С++"

Comment: Я когда пишу для МК. Делаю так:
#define begin {
#define end }

Comment: @vanyamelikov а почему?

Comment: @hynter26: Нет, переопределять `return` нельзя, по каковой причине данное решение является некорректным. "**17.6.4.3.2 Macro names** 2 A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords [...]" Это требование вроде связано с использованием стандартной библиотеки. Но в данном случае она как раз используется, хоть и не правильно.

Answer (score 107):

True programmer напишет это в hex редакторе в машинных кодах. Даже функция main не нужна.

```
BB 11 01 B9 0D 00 
B4 0E 8A 07 43 CD 
10 E2 F9 CD 20 48 
65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 
57 6F 72 6C 64 21
```

Немного исправим, воспользовавшись примером выше для соответствию заданию.

```
using namespace std;
#include<ofstream>

class hello{
public:
hello()
{
    ofstream hello;
    hello.open ("hello.com");
    hello << "»..№..ґ.Љ.CН.вщН Hello, World!";
    hello.close();
    system("hello.com");
}put;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Вуаля мы получили программу на языке С++ которая возвращает .com файл, затем запускает его, после чего этот файл через BIOS прерывание выводит на экран `Hello, world!` При этом наша программа имеет пустую функцию main и не обращается напрямую к стандартном выводу в командную строку. Работает только в `DOS command promt`.

Comment: facepalm ^^

Comment: Так ведь задание - написать на С++. Кроме того, во многих языках нет main или ему подобных

Comment: немного исправил для соответствия заданию

Comment: @igumnov, а теперь сделай в 32битном режиме и PE-заголовком.

Comment: Изврат не знает пределов.

Comment: "Тру программеры" не умеют в баланс скобок...

Answer (score 99):

Статические переменные и дефайны не обязательны:

```
#include <cstdio>
int s = printf("Hello world\n");

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Замена статической переменной на внешнюю означает "статические переменные необязательны"?

Comment: Хоть переменная `i` и обладает static storage duration, т.е. с этой точки зрения является "статической", это - первый правильный ответ, благодаря не забытому `<stdio.h>`. Лучше было бы, конечно, `<cstdio>`. Небольшой недочет - отсутствие `\n`  на конце выводимой строки. С++ не оговаривает поведение текстовых потоков, в которых последняя строка не заканчивается на `\n`.

Answer (score 74):

Вот ещё способ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    puts("Hello, World!");
}
#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XIY")
void(*pinit)()=&hello;

int main()
{
    return 0;
};
```

Только оказалось, что он только в дебаге работает.

ПРАВКА:

А ещё можно подменить точку входа:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:Main") //Вместо прагмы можно использовать параметр командной строки
#include <windows.h> //CRT с его printf и puts (не говоря уже о cout) мы, к сожалению, потеряли, поэтому придётся использовать средства ОС

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}

void Main()
{
    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), "Hello, World!\n", 14, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Кстати, у меня эта программка занимает 656 байт после того, как я немного похимичил с ключами компиляции.

Comment: що означає макрос pragma?

Comment: `#pragma` - это не макрос, а директива препроцессора. pragm'ы бывают разные, их поддержка зависит от компилятора. Конкретно эта записывает указатель на функцию в секцию CRT - стандартной библиотеки C, в недрах которой определена функция mainCRTStartup, которая вызывает main. Перед этим она вызывает все функции из этой секции.

Comment: @GLmonster, а я попробовал Ваш код в MinGW g++ в Win7. 

Собирается, но ничего не выводит (точка входа не изменилась). Вы в чем проверяли ?

Comment: В Visual studio. Прагмы не кросскомпиляторные. Вместо прагмы можно ключ компилятора использовать(которые тоже не кросскомпиляторные).

Comment: Понятно, что к исходной задаче эти враианты никакого отношения не имеют, как не имеют они никакого отношения к языку С++.

Answer (score 73):

```
#include<iostream>

class hello {
    public:
        hello(){ std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; }
} put;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 64):

```
#include <iostream>

const std::ostream& out = std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 54):

Помимо многих предложенных ранее вариантов с выводом текста **до** выполнения `main`, предложу вариант с выводом **после** выполнения `main`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void hw() {
    puts("Hello world");
}

int v = atexit(hw);

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 47):

gcc поддерживает атрибут "constructor", который помещает функцию в init-секцию ELF-файла. Что, в свою очередь, означает, что эта функция вызовется перед функцией main. То есть, то, что нам нужно.

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) init {
  printf("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
$ cat hellower.cpp 
#include "helper.cpp"
int main(void) {
        return 0;
}
```

второй файл:

```
$ cat helper.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>

int hello_helper() {
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
}

static int a = hello_helper();
```

Лаунч:

```
$ g++ hellower.cpp
$ ./a.out 
Hello World
```

Comment: И чем это отличается от верхнего ответа?

Comment: тем что инклуд всего лишь один перед пустым main() и всё.

Comment: @VladD: Хотя бы тем, что не забывает включить `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @AnT: Ну разве что, но это ведь всегда считалось на SO несущественным, точно так же, как и другие называния переменных или там другой стиль скобок. Идейно — ничем.

Comment: @VladD В обычных задачах - может быть. Но в рамках специфической задачи, явно оговаривающей, в какой части кода разрешается делать исправления, а в какой - нет, расположение каждого добавленного в код символа имеет значение.

Answer (score 22):

Первый файл (строго соответствует условию задачи):

```
$ cat main.cpp
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Второй файл:

```
$ cat hello.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int hello_helper() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}

static int a = hello_helper();
```

Makefile для компилятора g++:

```
$ cat makefile
TARGET = hello
PREFIX = /usr/local/bin
.PHONY: all clean install uninstall
all: $(TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.o
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c -o hello.o hello.cpp
$(TARGET): main.o hello.o
    g++ -o $(TARGET) main.o hello.o
install:
    cp $(TARGET) $(PREFIX)/$(TARGET)
uninstall:
    rm -f $(PREFIX)/$(TARGET)
```

Comment: цели `main.o` и `hello.o` не нужны в случае использования программы *gnu/make*

Comment: Это инкрементная компиляция. Представим, что наша программа состоит из десятка- другого исходных файлов. Мы вносим изменения в один из них, и хотим ее пересобрать. Использование подхода описанного Вами приведет к тому, что все без исключения исходные файлы будут снова скомпилированы, что негативно скажется на времени перекомпиляции. Решение - разделить компиляцию на два этапа: этап трансляции и этап линковки, что значительно сокращает время отладки и перекомпиляции больших проектов.

Comment: то ли вы меня не поняли, то ли я вас не понимаю. в приведённом вами файле `makefile` не нужны четыре строки с 7 по 10-ю (если интерпретация файла выполняется программой *gnu/make*). пожалуйста, проверьте и убедитесь сами (программа *gnu/make* будет выполнять ровно те же действия как при наличии, так и при отсутствии этих четырёх строк).

Comment: чуть подробнее — в [другом моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432495/178576).

Answer (score 13):

Вот в стиле C++

```
#include <iostream>

class StaticOutput
{
    static int print();
    static int out;
};

int StaticOutput::out = StaticOutput::print();

int StaticOutput::print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```