# Создание makefile

Tags: c++, компиляция, makefile

Пытаюсь разобраться в написании грамотного make файла, это ад.

Есть такие файлы: SubClass.h/.cpp, SuperClass.h/.cpp, Main.cpp.

Сконструировал такой makefile:

```
Programm: Main.o SuperClass.o SubClass.o
    g++ -o Programm Main.o SuperClass.o SubClass.o
Main.o: Main.cpp SuperClass.o SubClass.o
    g++ -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
SuperClass.o: SuperClass.h SuperClass.cpp
    g++ -c -o SuperClass.o SuperClass.cpp
SubClass.o: SubClass.cpp SubClass.h SuperClass.o
    g++ -c -o SubClass.o SubClass.cpp
```

Классно бы это автоматизировать и разделить по директориям /h /cpp /o файлы.

Нашел хороший способ получать зависимости (через include bash добавил в makefile)

```
g++ -MM SubClass.cpp
SubClass.o: SubClass.cpp SubClass.h SuperClass.h
```

А нужно что бы выхлоп был `SubClass.o: SubClass.cpp SubClass.h SuperClass.o`, не понимаю, как мне этого добиться с помощью make? Я явно делаю что то не так.

Через wildecard научился получать список файлов в папке, а вот в подпапках как (нахождение самих подпапок и тд)?

Это ведь такая простая и популярная модель организации проекта, неужели нет ничего готового? Возможно я пишу велосипед? :D

PS: Я не прошу что то писать за меня, просто наведите в нужное направление.

Comment: можно полученный список сохранить в переменную, а потом заменить  с помощью subst расширения. А можно просто взять cmake/scons/qmake/XXXmake и сделать простенький файл, который сам сделает makefile

Comment: +1 к CMake. Непонимаю я вообще, зачем сейчас писать самому makefile - это ведь ужасно.

Comment: @ixSci, например, в целях использования возможностей `gnu/make` для задач, не связанных с программированием вообще и на `c[++]` в частности.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

мне кажется, ваш файл несколько многословен. для всех описанных действий, кажется, достаточно таких строк:

```
Programm: Main.o SuperClass.o SubClass.o
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

запуск `make` с параметром `-n` (*dry-run*) показывает такую последовательность команд (при наличии в текущем каталоге только *cpp-* и *h-файлов*):

```
g++    -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
g++    -c -o SuperClass.o SuperClass.cpp
g++    -c -o SubClass.o SubClass.cpp
g++ -o Programm Main.o SuperClass.o SubClass.o
```

---

**немного объяснений по поводу «применённой магии»**

«магия» называется [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

все актуальные *implicit rules* (и ещё многое другое) можно посмотреть командой `make -p | less`.

к примеру, о том, что из `file.cpp` можно собарть `file.o` (и, главное, *как* это сделать), *make* «знает» благодаря вот такому правилу:

```
%.o: %.cpp
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Comment: +1, но не могли бы вы подробнее расписать магию? Откуда берутся недостающие вызовы?

Comment: @VladD, «магия» называется [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). или под «расписать» вы подразумевали дополнить ответ объяснениями, примерами и т.п.?

Comment: Ну хотя бы ссылкой на то, что происходит. То есть что .cpp -> .o есть в implicit rules.

Comment: Ого! А можно менять эти самые implicit rules? Например, включить `-MMD`, как в другом ответе, чтобы автоматически генерировались зависимости?

Comment: @VladD, добавить опцию, конечно, можно, переопределив (точнее, дополнив), например, переменную `$(COMPILE.cpp)` (или какую-нибудь из тех, из которых эта переменная составляется). только вот насчёт того, что получится в результате добавления опции `-MM` ко всем вызовам `g++` я сказать не берусь: я вообще в компиляции и программировании «не гуру», а *make* использую для «мирных», не-программистских целей.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 5):

> А нужно что бы выхлоп был `SubClass.o: SubClass.cpp SubClass.h SuperClass.o`

А зачем? Зачем при перекомпиляции SuperClass.cpp перекомпилировать SubClass.cpp?

Почему бы не сделать так:

```
Gpp = g++
srcs = SubClass.cpp SuperClass.cpp main.cpp
objs = $(srcs:.cpp=.o)
deps = $(srcs:.cpp=.d)

program: $(objs)
    $(Gpp) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(Gpp) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

# $(RM) is rm -f by default
clean:
    $(RM) $(objs) $(deps) program

-include $(deps)
```

Поясняю:

g++ сам сгенерит файлы с зависимостями (.d).

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(Gpp) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

Это правило сборки каждого `.o` файла, которое выполняет g++ с параметром `-MMD`, которая генерирует файл с зависимости (без системных файлов). Файлы с зависимостями перегенерируются только при изменении исходников.

objs=,deps= генерируем список файлов с помощью встроенной [возможности замены в make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs)

`$@` и `$<` так называемые ["автоматические переменные"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables). 
`$<` - имя первой зависимости (first prerequisite).  `$@` - имя цели для правила (выходного файла) (target file name).

Пример:

```
hello.o: hello.c hello.h
         gcc -c $< -o $@
```

`$@` = hello.o - имя выходного файла. `$<` = hello.c hello.h - входные файлы

В последней строчке мейкфайла включаем файлы с зависимостями (`-` в начале строки означает игнорировать ошибки.

Comment: +1, но не могли бы вы подробнее расписать, что происходит? Заклинания наподобие `$^` и `$<` неочевидны.

Comment: Круто, спасибо! Узнал что-то новое.

Comment: @VladD, по поводу переменных (и других ключевых слов): если установлена документация к `make` (обычно пакет называется `make-doc`), то можно воспользоваться такой командой для просмотра глоссария: `info make Name Index` (а «с самого начала» так: `info make`).

Comment: %.o: %.cpp, в какой момент это правило срабатывает? Где неявный вызов?

Comment: @uskabuska `program: $(objs)`

Answer (score 4):

Обычно мы сравнительно редко пишем makefile, а вся вроде бы освоенная "магия" так и норовит за полгода улетучиться из головы. Поэтому я стараюсь писать простые Makefile, вроде такого (для вашего случая).

```
# Эти обозначения я вечно забываю:
# $@ target
# $^ all right part
# $? only new in right part
# $< first name from right part
#

#CC = gcc
#CFLAGS = -g -std=gnu99

CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -O3  -pthread

SRCS  = SubClass.cpp SuperClass.cpp main.cpp

PROGS = programm

all: $(PROGS) 

programm: main.o SubClass.o SuperClass.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -pthread

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGS) *.o *~ *.bak a.out

depend:
    @makedepend -Y -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRCS) 2>/dev/null
# DO NOT DELETE

SubClass.o: f.h data.h
main.o: f.h
```

Строки после `depend` с зависимостями .o от .h добавляет команда `makedepend` (символ @ перед ней подавляет ее вывод в stdout), которая исполняется, когда мы запускаем

```
> make depend
```

после изменения состава файлов проекта или добавления наших (не системных) `.h` файлов в какой-нибудь `.cpp`

Когда мы вызываем

```
make
```

без аргументов, то Makefile начинает выполняться с первой метки (остальные, если не зависят от нее, уже не будут рассматриваться). Здесь `all:` вроде бы излишня (можно было бы сразу начать файл с `programm:`), но иногда хочется одним вызовом make собрать сразу несколько модулей и тогда они просто перечисляются в переменной `PROGS`.

Здесь я в `main.cpp` включаю `f.h`, в `SubClass.cpp` включаю `f.h` и `data.h`, а в `SuperClass.cpp` ничего не включаю.

Make по умолчанию строит зависимости .o от .cpp (или .c) и вызывает g++ с подстановкой значения из переменной `CXXFLAGS` (а для gcc использует `CFLAGS`).

Ключи для линкера (вызов $(CC) -o ...) я предпочитаю прописывать явно либо в команде, либо в переменных makefile, которые туда подставляю. Это может сберечь кучу времени при отладке через год-другой (особенно если при вызове make образуется длиннющая "простыня").

Если для компиляции какого-либо файла требуются нестандартные действия, то это прописываем вручную. Например, мы хотим (может быть иногда) использовать  при компиляции файла `SubClass.cpp` переменную препроцессора `TEST`. Тогда напишем

```
SubClass.o: SubClass.cpp Makefile
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -DTEST $<
```

где нибудь между `all:` и `depend:`. В таком случае мы должны включать в аргументы выполняемой команды переменную `CXXFLAGS` явно. Я написал здесь еще и зависимость от самого `Makefile`, чтобы при редактировании `-DTEST` проходила перекомпиляция SubClass.o и дальше пересборка programm.

Вот результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$ make clean
rm -rf programm *.o *~ *.bak a.out
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$ make
g++ -O3  -pthread   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -O3  -pthread -c -DTEST SubClass.cpp
g++ -O3  -pthread   -c -o SuperClass.o SuperClass.cpp
g++ -o programm main.o SubClass.o SuperClass.o -pthread
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$ ./programm 
f1()
f2(): xaxa
```

Теперь отредактируем Makefile, уберем `-DTEST` при компиляции SubClass.cpp

```
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$ make
g++ -O3  -pthread -c  SubClass.cpp
g++ -o programm main.o SubClass.o SuperClass.o -pthread
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$ ./programm 
f2(): xaxa
avp@avp-ubu1:tmake$
```

Comment: (makedepend: warning:  SubClass.cpp, line 1: cannot find include file "iostream") Можно ли указать makedepend игнорировать стандартные инклюды? (#include<>) И чем makedepend лучше указанию компилятору генерирования зависимостей?

Comment: @uskabuska, действительно, `makedepend` не знает о С++ инклюдах, поэтому я и перенаправляю ее stderr в /dev/null. Для того, чтобы зависимости от стандартных /usr/include/...h не прописывались используем ключ -Y, а свои оглавления с .h файлами (кроме ./) надо записывать в CXXFLAGS ( -I../ -I./myheaders и т.д.). Получаем в результате `makedepend -Y -- $(CXXFLAGS) -- $(SRCS) 2>/dev/null` / Чем makedepend лучше? Не знаю, может даже хуже, просто я ничем другим никогда не пользовался. / Так что можете изучить этот вопрос и доложить здесь (формат: вопрос и свой же ответ на него).