# Makefile и include

Tags: c++, компиляция, makefile

На основе [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432480/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-makefile), cпасибо вам, сделал такой вот скрипт:

```
CPP = $(shell find "cpp/" -name "*.cpp")

DFILE = dependence.d
Programm: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPP))
    g++ -MM $(CPP) >$(DFILE)
    g++ -o Programm $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPP))
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $^
include $(DFILE)
```

Но он не ведет учет зависимостей, которые находятся в DFILE, а они есть там, генерация проходит верно. Как я неправильно пользуюсь include?

1 Узнаю все файлы в cpp/*.cpp

3 Объявляю переменную для хранения имени файла зависимости DFILE = dependence.d

4 Цель Programm, переименовываю сpp на o в строчке зависимостей

5 Генерация файла зависимостей

6 Сборка на основе прописанных зависимостей на 6той строке, все зависимости, для цели,
 выполнятся по правилу на 10той строке

Тк во время первой сборки файл пуст DFILE - никаких дополнительных зависимостей нет.

Во второй сборке, я изменил SubClass.h, все эти действия повторяются и должны быть учтены зависимости созданные при прошлой сборке - файл зависимостей не пуст, но этого у меня никак не получается. 
PS: Я в прогрессе сделаю отдельную цель Dependence, для обновления зависимостей, но мне бы с этим разобраться.
Файл зависимостей:

```
SubClass.o: cpp/SubClass.cpp cpp/../h/SubClass.h \
 cpp/../h/../h/SuperClass.h
SuperClass.o: cpp/SuperClass.cpp cpp/../h/SuperClass.h
Main.o: cpp/Main.cpp cpp/../h/SuperClass.h cpp/../h/SubClass.h \
 cpp/../h/../h/SuperClass.h
```

Comment: вероятно, вы ожидаете, что файл будет создан при выполнении одного из правил, и `make` тут же перезапустится и выполнит все действия повторно, но уже с учётом нового содержимого этого файла? нет, `make` сначал прочитывает все `includ`-ы, строит алгоритм последовательности действий, а потому уже их выполняет.

Comment: кстати, неплохо бы привести и содержимое сгенерировавшегося файла `dependence.d`

Comment: правило `%.o: %.cpp; g++ -c -o $@ $^` — вообще не нужно, т.к. просто повторяет существующее implicit rule. см. мой ответ к вашему предыдущему вопросу.

Comment: вы напишите, пожалуйста, чего именно вы ожидаете, и что происходит не так.

Comment: alexander barakin, обновил :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. я бы порекомендовал отказаться от идеи раскладывать файлы по каталогам в зависимости от их суффикса: мне кажется, это плохая идея.
2. но если «очень нужно», то вот `makefile`, который, надеюсь, выполняет именно то, что требуется:

```
CPP = $(wildcard cpp/*.cpp)
objects = $(patsubst cpp/%.cpp,%.o,$(CPP))
DFILE = dependence.d

Programm: $(objects); g++ -o $@ $^

$(DFILE):; g++ -MM $(CPP) >$(DFILE)

%.o: cpp/%.cpp; $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

include $(DFILE)
```

сначала надо создать файл с зависимостями:

```
$ make dependence.d
```

а затем уже всё остальное:

```
$ make
```

Comment: А где у вас определенны COMPILE.cpp и OUTPUT_OPTION?              PS: Я видел в некоторых ide автоматически генерируют h/ cpp/ o/абсолютно идентичные иерархические директории, только для хранения различных расширений файлов. Чем это не удобно?

Comment: *А где у вас определенны COMPILE.cpp и OUTPUT_OPTION?* — «входят в поставку»: см. вывод `make -p`, про который я писал в ответе к вашему предыдущему вопросу. / *Чем это не удобно?* — если вам удобно, то так и делайте. но такое распределение файлов по каталогам не является распространённой практикой (вероятно, не напрасно). собственно, я нигде и не встречал подобного, хотя исходников разных свободных проектов по работе насмотрелся «более чем много». но так как не являюсь «гуру» в программировании, я не смогу вам аргументированно объяснить недостатки такого подхода.

Comment: *А где у вас определенны COMPILE.cpp и OUTPUT_OPTION?* — эту команду я, собственно, просто скопировал из `implicit rules` (см. `make -p`). можете смело заменить её, например, на `g++ -c -o $@ $<`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял где был не прав.