# Компиляция только выбранных файлов с помощью Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnumake

Нужен *Makefile*, который бы компилировал только те файлы, которые указаны в переменной `SRCS`.

Например, есть следующая структура файлов:

```
test/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
    c.cpp
    d.cpp
    ...
    Makefile
```

*Makefile*:

```
SRCS = a.cpp c.cpp ...
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

???
```

Что написать далее чтобы каждый файл из `SRCS` компилировался в соответствующий объектный файл из `OBJS`. Не все `.cpp` файлы, а только выбранные.

Переменная `SRCS` может меняться со временем. И это бывает необходимо не только для компиляции `.cpp` файлов в объектные `.o`, но и для других задач.

Comment: **второй** вопрос, поданный как «дополнение», лучше задать отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

минимально достаточно одной строки:

```
SRCS = a.cpp c.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(OBJS)
```

тогда, при наличии в текущем каталоге файлов `a.cpp` и `c.cpp`, будет такой результат:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++    -c -o c.o c.cpp
```

и в текущем же каталоге «волшебным образом» появятся файлы `a.o` и `c.o`.

подробности о применённой «магии» — [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432495/178576).

---

> И это бывает необходимо не только для компиляции `.cpp` файлов в объектные `.o`, но и для других задач.

когда появятся *конкретизированные* новые задачи, с которыми возникнут трудности, задавайте новые вопросы. общего ответа «на все случаи жизни» — увы, нет.

Comment: Где указывать `--std=c++14`?

Comment: это опция компилятора? добавьте её в переменную, например, `CPPFLAGS`: `CPPFLAGS+=--std=c++14`