# GNU Make C++. Linux

Tags: c++, makefile

Возможно, не совсем понимая что искать, не могу найти действующего примера. 
Проект на C++, разбит на подпапки(src:Engine{Component, Utils}, Process{Objects,...,etc}). Как описать MakeFile, чтобы он собирал исходники по папкам? Из всего, что наскрёб, увидел вариацию "в каждой папке по MakeFile", что немного дезориентировало. Если это тот самый способ, есть ли необходимость повторения в каждом указания используемых библиотек(Boost'a, к примеру), флагов и т.д. ?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если здесь нужно применять знания трансляции и линковки в C/C++
и использовать их уже в совокупности с Make, просьба оставить ссылки на ресурсы. Но лучше это на тот случай, если имеется ряд подводных крестов в этом деле.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> увидел вариацию "в каждой папке по MakeFile"

наличие отдельного файла с инструкциями для программы *gnu/make* в каждом сборочном каталоге не всегда обязательно, хотя, наверно, удобно.

#### вместо тысячи слов лучше привести примитивный пример

пусть имеется такая структура файлов/каталогов:

```
$ tree
.
├── GNUmakefile
├── program.cpp
└── somepart
    └── somecode.cpp

1 directory, 3 files
```

минимально необходимое содержимое файла GNUmakefile для данного случая — всего одна строка, декларирующая, что «для получения `program` нужны `program.o` и `somepart/somecode.o`»:

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
program: program.o somepart/somecode.o
```

проверяем, какие команды будет выполнять *make* (опция `-n`, она же `--dry-run`, только выводит последовательность команд, не выполняя их):

```
$ make -n
g++    -c -o program.o program.cpp
g++    -c -o somepart/somecode.o somepart/somecode.cpp
cc   program.o somepart/somecode.o   -o program
```

чуть подробнее о том, откуда программа *make* всё это взяла — в [другом моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432495/178576).

---

надо добавить что-нибудь в (например) опции для *c++*? используйте подходящую переменную:

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
CXXFLAGS += -I/путь/к/boost
program: program.o somepart/somecode.o
```

проверка:

```
$ make -n
g++ -I/путь/к/boost   -c -o program.o program.cpp
g++ -I/путь/к/boost   -c -o somepart/somecode.o somepart/somecode.cpp
cc   program.o somepart/somecode.o   -o program
```

---

если всё-таки подребуется отдельный файл, то [вызывается он обычно рецептом вида](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html):

```
$(MAKE) -C подкаталог
```

чтобы вызываемому экземпляру программы *gnu/make* «попала» какая-нибудь переменная, надо её явно экспортировать с помощью директивы `export` в «основном» файле:

```
export CXXFLAGS += ...
```