# Как удалить временные файлы в Makefile, сохранив инкрементальную компиляцию?

Tags: makefile

У меня есть Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: bin\hello.exe

clean:
    rmdir bin /S /Q

bin\hello.exe: bin\main.o bin
    gcc bin\main.o -o bin\hello.exe
    del bin\main.o

bin\main.o: bin
    gcc main.c -c -o bin\main.o

bin:
    mkdir bin
```

Он работает, но при удалении временных файлов перестаёт работать инкрементальная компиляция: при наборе команды `mingw32-make` или `mingw32-make all` проект компилируется полностью.

Но ведь цель all у меня не зависит от временных файлов, а только от exe. Как при построении удалить временные файлы, но при этом оставить компиляцию инкрементальной? Или надо делать отдельную цель наподобие `release`, которая всё соберёт, но в дополнение к этому удалит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видимые с первого взгляда недочёты:

1. вы указали пререквизитом (часто говорят «зависимостью») каталог. а каталог «обновляется» при «обновлении» любого находящегося в нём файла.

   пример:

   ```
   цель: ... каталог
   ```

   «цель» будет «обновлена» после создания/удаления любого файла в каталоге (каталог окажется «новее», чем эта цель).

   если для выполнения цели требуется, чтобы каталог просто существовал, но не было зависимости от его времени модификации (на что и ориентируется интерпретатор *make* при определении того, какие цели требуют обновления), используйте [«order-only» пререквизиты](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html). они отделяются от «нормальных» пререквизитов символом вертикальной черты. слева от вертикальной черты — «нормальные» пререквизиты (ноль или более), справа — «order-only» (минимум один):

   ```
   цель: ... | каталог
   ```
2. вот в этом правиле нет в пререквизитах файла `main.c`:

   ```
   bin/main.o:
       gcc main.c -c -o bin/main.o
   ```

   а учитывая, что вы ещё к тому же намеренно «вручную» удаляете `bin/main.o` в процессе сборки (чего делать не стоит), последний (и «зависящий» от него `bin/hello.exe`) будет компилироваться при каждом запуске *make*.

---

по поводу промежуточных файлов и их удаления подробно изложено в [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules).

для вашего случая (когда вы намеренно уклоняетесь от использования [implicit rules](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432495/178576)) подойдёт явное указание файла `bin/main.o` как промежуточного:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: bin/main.o
```

после добавления этой строки (и устранения изложенных выше недочётов) «чистая» сборка (когда каталога `bin` нет) завершится автоматическим удалением промежуточного файла `bin/main.o`

Comment: Я читал про implicit rules, но ничего не понял. Надо подумать, как сформулировать вопросы по этой теме, чтобы прояснить её для себя.

Comment: начните с элементарного: в **пустом** каталоге создайте **один** файл `hello.c` (классический «привет мир») и запустите `make hello`.

Comment: В Linux работает. В Windows не работает, т.к. там нет приложения cc, которое пытается запустить mingw32-make.

Comment: вот вы уже и начали разбираться с implicit rules. поздравляю! // p.s. напоминаю, что просмотреть эти правила можно, передав опцию `-p` программе *make* (для чистоты лучше запускать её в пустом каталоге).

Comment: Оказывается, эта документация есть на русском языке: http://linux.yaroslavl.ru/docs/prog/gnu_make_3-79_russian_manual.html

Comment: Почти работает: повторный вызов  make ничего не пересобирает. Но если поменять один из файлов исходного кода, всё равно пересобираются все. Но вообще, я так подумал - это же логично, как он всё пересоберёт, если файлы удалены? Так что правильный ответ на мой вопрос - однозначно никак.