# Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Tags: bash, makefile

Имею следующий Makefile:

```
./object_files/server.o: ./source_files/server.c ./header_files/server.h
    if which gcc 
    then
    gcc -c ./source_files/server.c
    mv ./server.o ./object_files/server.o
    elif which clang
    then
    clang -c ./source_files/server.c
    mv ./server.o ./object_files/server.o
    else    
    echo -e "\033[31m\033[5mPlease, install a compilar for C language such as gcc or clang!!!\033[0m\n"
    fi

./executable_files/server: ./object_files/server.o
    if which gcc
    then
    gcc -o ./executable_files/server  ./object_files/server.o
    elif which clang
    then
    clang -o ./executable_files/server ./object_files/server.o
    else
    echo -e "\033[31m\033[5mPlease, install a compilar for C language such as gcc or clang!!!\033[0m\n"
    fi
```

Вывод консоли:

```
if which gcc 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
make: *** [Makefile:2: object_files/server.o] Error 2
```

Comment: а почему один раз не определить переменную в виде CC=gcc или СС=clang и потом просто подставлять $(CC)

Comment: @KoVadim, если использовать «каноническое» имя переменной CC, то его и подставлять не надо (см. мой ответ). впрочем, не все программисты приемлют принцип «kiss». увы…

Comment: зависит от задачи, может человеку нужно два компилятора одновременно, тогда да, плохая идея. А может ему любой подходящий, тогда эту переменную можно по необходимости переопределить извне. Негоже makefile заниматься таким.

Answer (score 1):

Каждая строчка в мейкфайле выполняется как отдельная команда, за
исключением случаев, когда конец предыдущей экранирован.  Так что:

```make
./object_files/server.o: ./source_files/server.c ./header_files/server.h
  if which gcc;\
  then\
    gcc -c ./source_files/server.c;\
    mv ./server.o ./object_files/server.o;\
  elif which clang;\
  then\
    clang -c ./source_files/server.c;\
    mv ./server.o ./object_files/server.o;\
  else\   
    echo -e "\033[31m\033[5mPlease, install a compilar for C language such as gcc or clang!!!\033[0m\n";\
  fi
```

Я лично всегда подобные вещи просто кладу в отдельный скрипт.

Comment: Все зделан, но все равно есть эта ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

1. в программировании считается хорошим тоном переиспользовать существующий код
2. к чему все эти манипуляции с подкаталогами? [kiss](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) вроде никто пока не отменял. у программы *gnu/make* по этому поводу есть удобная «магия».

если избавиться от дублирования кода и поместить файлы `server.c` и `server.h` в текущий каталог, то ровно той же функциональности можно добиться гораздо более лаконичным (а потому проще поддерживаемым) кодом:

```
CC = $(shell command -v gcc || command -v clang)
ifeq ($(CC),)
$(error Please, install a compilar for C language such as gcc or clang!!!)
endif

server:

server.o: server.c server.h
```

---

p.s. подробнее о применённой «[магии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432495/178576)» (или в [первоисточнике: implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html)).

Comment: Стоит добавить, что это *GNU Make*.  *POSIX Make* не умеет ни `$(shell …)`, ни `$(error …)`, ни `ifeq`.

Comment: хм. действительно, в процессе редактирования потерялось упоминание про gnu/make. надо добавить.