# Практическое применение std::atexit

Tags: c++

Сегодня я узнал о существовании функции `atexit`. Читая мануалы б ней, не могу понять, насколько практически необходимо использовать эту функцию, если можно завершить программу банальным закрытием по крестику окна или завершению кода (если консоль)?

**
@gil9red я видел этот пример по ссылке. Но до последнего не понимал, в каком случае можно применить эту функцию.
Изучив примеры использованию по ссылкам на гитхабе, я пришёл к понимаю (как я сам ощущаю) способа применения `atexit`.
Получается, что эта функция вызывается в любом случае, когда приложение завершается. То есть, реально можно реализовать сериализацию чего-либо, не прибегая к лишнему вызову из `main()` (ведь иногда можно попросту забыть сделать это :) ).
Небольшой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void CloseProj()
{
  cout << "Выполнение закончено. Программа закрыта\n";
}

void EnterName()
{
  char name[20];
  int age;

  cout << "Пожалуйста, введите своё имя и возраст:\n"
       << "Имя: ";
  cin >> name;
  cout << "Введите свой возраст: \n"
       << "Возраст: ";
  cin >> age;
  cout << "Привёт, " << name << ". Тебе " << age << " лет!\n";
}

int main()
{
  atexit(CloseProj);
  EnterName();
}
```

Comment: А эта функция не служит для закрытия программы... Скорее это предтечя деструкторов в с - выполнение некого кода по завершении работы. Ни малейшей необходимости использовать эту функцию в С++ нет.

Comment: Одно из возможных применений - это написать [Hello world с пустой функцией main](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496641/176217).

Comment: "...насколько практически необходимо использовать эту функцию, если можно завершить программу банальным закрытием по крестику окна"... Не понимаю вопроса. Звучит как "зачем нужно программное обеспечение, если всегда есть веротяность что кто-то просто выдернет вилку из розетки".

Comment: @AnT не правильно меня понял. Я приверженец парадигмы структурного программирования. В обычной ситуации для меня, функцию void CloseProj() описаную выше, я бы вызвал самостоятельно из main(), когда это было необходимо (то есть в конце). Позавчера я узнал, что существует atexit и впал в ступор, типа: неужели программы на C++ нужно (или можно) завершать как-то особенно. Читал, читал, а просветления не было :) А потом мне дали ссылки на гитхаб, плюс я сам написал пример и понял (выше), что функция atexit вызывается самостоятельно при завершении программы.

Comment: @AnT И теоретически, можно много чего вынести в atexit, чтобы не забыть. Как я уже сказал - например сериализация.

Comment: Век живи, век учись в общем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [источнику по ссылке](http://cppstudio.com/post/869/) функция `int atexit( void ( * funcptr ) (void) );`:

> Функция atexit при завершении работы программы передает управление другой функции, которая будет выполняться на выходе.

Т.е. это возможность выполнить какие-то действия перед тем как программа будет завершена, например: отправить уведомление по сети, сохранить какие-то данные, и т.п. Тут уже будет зависеть от фантазии программиста.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
 
void funcExit1(void)
{
  std::cout << "Выход функции 1n";
}
 
void funcExit2(void)
{
    std::cout << "Выход функции 2n";
}
 
int main()
{
  atexit(funcExit1); // При выходе из программы, запустить функцию funcexit1
  atexit(funcExit2); // При выходе из программы, запустить функцию funcexit2
  std::cout << "завершение main функцииn";
  return 0;
}
```

Консоль:

```
завершение main функции
Выход функции 2
Выход функции 1
```

---

Полное описание:

> Функция atexit при завершении работы программы передает управление
> другой функции, которая будет выполняться на выходе. Функция, на
> которую указывает аргумент *funcprt вызывается, в случае успешного
> завершения программы.
>
> Если функция atexit была вызвана более одного раза, то порядок
> выполнения функций, передаваемых в качестве аргумента, будет обратным.
> Такой принцип работы функции основан на работе стека, т.е. последняя
> вызванная функция будет выполняться первой.
>
> Одна единственная функция может быть зарегистрирована на выполнение
> более одного раза, после завершения работы программы.
>
> Реализация С++ должна поддерживать регистрацию по меньшей мере 32
> atexit функций.

---

Примеры практического использования из популярных репозиториев с++:

- [https://github.com/apple/swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bf5133d98659ed1ba03ec6b007a1258fb31705a5/lib/Immediate/REPL.cpp#L282)
- [https://github.com/nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/bab5826504ac04695c33954c07ff832fc7b4b2c8/test/thirdparty/Fuzzer/afl/afl_driver.cpp#L219)
- [https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4f94d82c7fc82164707947d56c35afadab98dfd5/torch/lib/c10d/ProcessGroupMPI.cpp#L255)
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv: [[1]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b39cd06249213220e802bb64260727711d9fc98c/3rdparty/libwebp/src/utils/utils.c#L111), [[2]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/dca657a2fde42a1c70c55881bfd128b6567a5946/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L259), [[3]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b39cd06249213220e802bb64260727711d9fc98c/3rdparty/libjasper/jas_init.c#L154)
- [https://github.com/electron/electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/a24ad6bc14d29c5cac69e83d3e38e2c3b9b210b8/atom/app/atom_main.cc#L119)
- [https://github.com/chromium/chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/7b15b3a088901e62e76a74c4a2303d070f8c5f17/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/webaudio/audio_node.cc#L62)

Comment: Вот зачем перепечатывать описание функции (с которым оп и так знаком, по его словам) когда вопрос был про практическое использование? Пример какой-то совсем бессмысленный.

Comment: А `отправить уведомление по сети, сохранить какие-то данные, и т.п. ` чем не пример практического использования?

Comment: А для "отправить уведомление по сети, сохранить какие-то данные, и т.п." нет ни малейшей необходимости прибегать к функции `atexit`. Даже если записать более конкретно "отправить уведомление по сети, сохранить какие-то данные, и т.п. при выходе из программы", то использовать `atexit` все равно будет ни к чему.

Comment: А если я хочу это сделать именно при завершении программы? Но, например, не руками вызывать в `main`, а в другом месте регистрируя, чтобы при завершении `main` было вызвано

Comment: По этому поводу хорошо написал Макконнелл: "Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живете". Если для того чтобы уяснить, что происходит перед завершением программы, кому-то придется вместо беглого взгляда на то, что идет перед `return 0`, лазить по всей кодовой базе  выискивая вызовы `atexit`, то он будет явно не в восторге. Кроме того, регистрация `atexit` мало того, что длиннее, так еще и не позволяет передавать в вызываемую функцию аргументы.

Comment: Среди ссылок-примеров, что добавил в ответ, есть пример с лямбдой и тот позволит использовать аргументы (хоть и нестандартно): `atexit([]() { OnThreadExit(nullptr, DLL_THREAD_DETACH, nullptr); });`. Да не вижу смысла осуждать `atexit`, когда есть препроцессорные директивы, которые позволяют в любом месте `true` на `false` поменять. Я не против и не за `atexit`, но раз он есть, то найдут ему применение :)

Comment: Нет, этот пример не позволяет использовать аргументы. Если у лямбды был бы не пустой список захвата или она принимала бы аргументы, то она бы не могла использоваться в качестве обработчика `atexit`. Что касается других примеров - в 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 явно нужно избавляться от `atexit`. Это все как раз примеры "как делать не надо". В 5 скорее какой-то костыль для отладочных целей, сидящий в блоке `#ifndef DEBUG`. Зато с подробным комментарием. И о каких таких "препроцессорных директивах, которые позволяют в любом месте true на false" тут идет речь? При чем тут эти директивы?

Comment: Вы ведь привели в качестве минуса atexit то, что их придется искать по всему проекту, чтобы понять что ожидать от программы. И мне показалось, что это очень похоже на препроцессорные замены, которые тоже могут быть не использованы, но их используют и активно

Comment: Странная логика. Препроцессорные замены меняют текст программы. Для препроцессорных директив есть сценарии, когда им нет альтернативы, например -  (частично) conditional compilation, генерация имен, превращение идентификаторов в текст, всякие спец макросы.  А тут для `atexit` есть альтернатива, которая покрывает все сценарии использования, и может даже больше.

Comment: Окей, вы знаете больше вариантов использования препроцессорных директив, у меня в памяти были `define` для замены констант, длинных типов, вставки функций, для которых можно обойтись стандартными способами. Это становится флудом, давайте закроем эту тему и вернемся в atexit. А какая есть альтернатива atexit?

Comment: Альтернатива - это выполнять то, что должно выполняться при выходе из программы, непосредственно при выходе из программы, то бишь перед `return` в `main`

Answer (score 0):

Вывод полной логистики на экран, хранимой внутри программы, состоянии переменных (для debugg-инга).

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic atexit.cpp
# include <cstdlib>
# include <iostream>

int globalX;

void exc(){
  std::cerr<<"globalX="<<globalX<<"\n";}

void  f(){
  globalX = 777 ;
  std::exit(1);
  globalX = 666 ;  }

int main(){
  if(std::atexit(exc)){
    std::cerr<<"main:std::atexit(exc)\n";
    return 1;}
  f();
  return 0;}
```

Comment: Бессмысленный совет. Глобальных переменных быть не должно. Но даже если они есть, их состояние можно и так в отладчике посмотреть, печатать их (ака printf-debugging) - это мартышкин труд. Тем более непонятно, зачем это делать, когда приложение выходит. И сам выход через `exit` использовать тоже нет ни малейшей необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть профессионалам  где нибудь и понадобится вызвать эту функцию, поскольку постольку(сужу чисто логически, но не уверен так ли это...) есть многочисленные старые коды, да и программировать  приходится коллективно, и  у каждого свой стиль,  собственная абстракция и  уровень знаний. С++ постоянно прогрессирует, появляются все новые и новые средства (классы, функции, библиотеки, приложения), но это не значит, что все что было раньше нужно выбросить. Те же массивы уже кажутся лишными, когда есть совершенно безопасные контейнеры (лично я не пользуюсь массивами, хотя часто пишу программы), но ведь они же используются по разным сооброжениям и нуждам. Не нужным могут выглядеть также очень многие(если не все) функции  языка С, например такие как `printf`,  `puts`..., но иногда ими пользоваться удобно, да и не все люди склонны быстро отбрасывать привычный стиль и  годами накопленные знания. В С++ можно уже обходится без простых указателей и  пользоваться только умными указательями, но задавать вопрос: "так зачем же нам  обычные указатели?"  не стоит, и т.д. и т.п. Так что `std::atexit`  пока еще существует в старых кодах и может встречаться в новых каких то, и если она есть в стандарте, означает ее  нужность, но в любом случаи хорошо быть информированным. Просто знать, но не думать как ее использовать, потому что нынче очень много возможностей для того, чтобы обходиться без этой функции(те же деструкторы) а думать как хорошо проектировать и написать хороший, читабельный, удовлетворяющий требованиям заказчика код. И чем больше у вас информации о существующих инструментах, предоставленными стандартом и приложением, тем больше вариантов для решения задачи у вас возникнут... 
P.S. Если плохо изложил или не то что надо, то заранее извеняюсь( все таки русский не мой родной язык и программирование не моя профессия). Просто  захотел поделиться своим мнением по этому поводу.

Answer (score 0):

На практике я использовал [atexit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) в программах, работающих с [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html) для удаления сегментов ([shmctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html)) при завершении процесса.

Кстати, аналогичная, но к сожалению, depricated функция [on_exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html)
(`Portable application should avoid this function, and use the standard atexit(3) instead.`)
на мой взгляд более удобна.