# Способы вывода текста без printf в main

Tags: c

Как можно вывести самую банально фразу `"Hello World!"`?
Но чтобы при этом, функция `main` была пустой, то есть без `printf("Hello World!") ;`

Comment: Навеяло [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/hello-world-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-main)? :) Поскольку там есть варианты, работающие и в С, повторять их здесь будет некузяво :) Так что обращайтесь туда..

Comment: @Harry *"варианты, работающие и в С"* Их там очень мало, кстати. На вскидку, это только `#define` и всякие нестандартные извраты с прагмами/`__attribute__`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Чуть ниже комментариев есть такое симпатичное поле ввода, называется - "Ваш ответ". Щелкните по нему мышкой и напишите свои варианты, отличные от приводившихся по указанной ссылке :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello World!\n")])
{
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06898c1365f0552f

Comment: Да, здорово! (и почти честно (формулировке вопроса полностью удовлетворяет), но все же printf вызывается уже после метки `main:` -))

Comment: Все же на грани фола...