# значение функции main

Tags: c

Для чего используют эту функцию?

Comment: С вызова этой функции начинается работа всей программы

Comment: ([хотя бывают и исключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811), но с этим поначалу лучше не заморачиваться)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: Что делает функция вообще? вычисляет и возвращает некое значение туда, откуда её вызвали. Кто вызывает функцию main? ну будем считать, что операционная система. Что может вернуть в ОС вызванная функция? код, который скажет, успешно она выполнена, или возникла ошибка. Почему именно main? а так исторически сложилось.

Answer (score 3):

Все программы, написанные на языке C, содержат основную функцию, которая должна иметь имя main. Ей передается управление сразу после запуска программы.

Comment: Нет, не все программы